# Why is my auxtree added via tlmgr not found by kpsewhich?

Tags: texlive, texlive-2017, kpsewhich

I am developing a style file locally and while I have the released version as part of my TEXMFHOME, I have the latest version of the style in git. When I develop with this git, I want to easily switch to that TEXMF and use it instead. On Windows with MiKTeX I used the `initexmf --user-roots= ...` command, but now it is time to transfer to Linux and TeX Live.

So what I understood is, that auxtrees would be the way to go here, so I called `sudo tlmgr conf auxtrees add /home/MYUSERNAME/my/location/texmfofme`. But if I compile a document, it seems TeXlive does not know about this location. So I called `tlmgr conf auxtrees show` and it shows:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
List of auxiliary texmf trees:
  /home/MYUSERNAME/my/location/texmfofme
```

I then found out, that I can also check with kpsewhich by calling `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFHOME`, but this only results in `/home/MYUSERNAME/texmf` and therefore I suspect I am missing something. I tried `texhash` as well, but with no success.

Version running is

```
> tex --version
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
```

and

```
> tlmgr --version
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
tlmgr revision 46207 (2018-01-04 19:34:36 +0100)
tlmgr using installation: /usr/share/texlive
TeX Live (http://tug.org/texlive) version 2017
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

### Update

I figured out, that asking kpsewhich for `TEXMFHOME` if adding an auxtree is a bit stupid, I should ask for `AUXTREES`, don't you think? So I called `kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFAUXTREES` and the result is `{}`, even though `tlmgr conf auxtrees show` still shows my added path.

Is `tlmgr` maybe writing to the wrong `texmf.cnf` file? I think it uses `/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf`, but I don't know, if this is right.

### Another update

I now found out, that calling `kpsewhich -all texmf.cnf` should show me, which configuration files are used and it returns:

```
/etc/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/texmf.cnf
```

As you can see, `/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf` is not in the list, is that the issue?

### Further investigations

I now got a working configuration, but only through manual intervention. What did I do? I moved the file `/usr/share/texlive/texmf.cnf` to `/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c/texmf.cnf` and manually added the line `TEXMFAUXTREES = /home/MYUSERNAME/my/location/texmfofme,`. The `,` at the end is important, you can also put a `:` there, which as far as I understand allows `kpathsea` to look further for files. After setting this manually, my graphic is found and can be used.

So my new question is: Why does `tlmgr` modify a file that is not found by `kpathsea`? Is there maybe something wrong in my general config, in a system variable or so?

Comment: If I remember correctly the auxtrees option was  added in 2019. Do you perhaps have two tex systems?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer not that I am aware of, it is a recent installation and I only installed texlive through `apt-get`, nothing else. I added the versioning of `tlmgr` in my question, if that is of help.

Comment: hm, time flies. It was added in 2017. How do you know that texlive doesn't use the location?

Comment: Because I am referring to images that are stored in the added TEXMF tree that I add as an auxtree, but they are not found by PDFlatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I‘d be happy to use another mechanism than auxtree, my requirement is that I can add a folder temporary through a script and remove it later. So none of the standard TEXMF trees works, as I don‘t want to move my files there.

Comment: where are they stored in the auxtree? And does the auxtree have an ls-R file and if yes did you update it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110492/discussion-between-tobibs-and-ulrike-fischer).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer do we even know if the auxtrees feature works on the Debian modified tlmgr? A lot might have happened since 2017

Comment: @daleif is that what tlmgr means when it says running on Debian, switching to user mode? Unfortunately I have to stay with Ubuntu 18.04 for the time. Is there another approach then auxtrees that I can make use of? Because the root cause seems to be tlmgr loading the wrong texmf.cnf file.

Comment: Yes. I also use that Ubuntu, but I **never** use the latex installed through Ubuntu packages, I use the upstream unmodified one. I know for a fact that auxtrees work in thst one as I use it myself. The upstream one is available at TUG.org/texlive

Comment: `tlmgr` is disabled because it conflicts with `apt`.  But another solution has been offered by the debian maintainer:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632156/205379