# Finding XML files with kpsewhich

Tags: kpathsea

What is the right way to store XML or DTD files in a `texmf` tree and to configure my system so that `kpsewhich` will be able to find them?

Running `kpsewhich -help-formats` shows nothing about xml files, and the "other text files" option shows a path involving `$TEXMF/kpsewhich//` which is not really where I would like to have my files, I would rather put them in `$TEXMF/tralics/xml` or some place like that.

Setting `TEXINPUTS` to add the whole texmf tree works, but feels wrong.

I guess the proper way would be to teach kpathsea about a new file type but I found nowhere in the documentation how to do that. Is it possible?

Comment: which tool should then find the files per kpsewhich?

Comment: a shell script that runs xmllint

Comment: `find  /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex -name \*.xml | wc -l` says that there are already 270 xml files in the standard texlive TEXINPUTS tree so adding a few more seems quite reasonable.

Comment: Hm, and indeed `kpsewhich` finds those...

Comment: Investigating, I ended up finding that my problem might actually be related to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553084/why-is-my-auxtree-added-via-tlmgr-not-found-by-kpsewhich

Comment: So in texlive, `kpsewhich` finds .cls files in `texmf-dist` and in an auxtree, and finds .xml files in `texmf-dist` but not in an auxtree

Comment: That sounds wrong, if the file would be found with  .tex extension it should be found with .xml (the question you link to is unresolved but seems to be a local configuration error rather than anything about the intended behaviour)

Comment: I just added an xml file in a folder tex/xml in a local auxtree and kpsewhich worked fine: `kpsewhich testxml.xml` gave `..../UFlocaltexmf/tex/xml/testxml.xml`. But I don't think that a folder outside the tex folder can work without changes in the search pathes.

Comment: OK, so the easiest is to add everything below `/tex/` then. Not TDS-compliant but so be it, as that will be for a local install. Thanks for your help!